# Switch has a hot wire activated by another switch

Tags: wiring, switch, light

I have a box with two switches.  One of the switches goes to a ceiling light.  The second switch we have never been able to determine.  Today I decided to try to figure out where that second switch goes.

Taking off the cover, it looks like original 1959 construction.  I don't want to pull the switches out because I am afraid I will never get the box put back together.  It looks over crowded to me, but I am not ready to deal with that today.

Anyway, I can see four black wires twisted together and two blacks going to each switch.  With my non-contact tester, I find the bottom black on both switches to be hot.  When I flip the first (ceiling light) switch, the top black wire now shows hot **but** the top black wire on the second (mystery) switch **also** shows hot, even though it is in the off position.

Basically, with he first switch on, both wires going to the second switch are hot.

1. Is there a legitimate reason for this ever?
2. Is this as unsafe as it feels?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you turn the first switch off and the second switch on, what happens?

Comment: What's the wiring in the ceiling light junction box? Is it possible there once was a fan, and now the two lives for fan and light (2 switches) are tied together there?

Comment: The easy cure for overcrowding is a "Legrand Wiremold Surface Conduit Starter Box". instant 10 cubic inches.   Are any receptacles switched?  You have to check both sockets on each receptacle as they can be controlled separately.

Comment: Use a multi meter instead of your wonder stick to test the wires. Non contact tester are known for inaccurate voltages in close quarters.

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for your help!

ThreePhaseEel - With the first switch off and the second switch on, the second switch is hot at the top and bottom.

P2000 - Long story...The ceiling light is a two-unit track light that could be original.  The ceiling has a circular texture pattern with no evidence of historical changes.  If they patched if perfectly it would be the only place in the house where they have done so.  There is a circular patch 15 feet away at the other end of the room that could have been a light/fan in the past.

Comment: Also,

Harper - Thanks for the tip.  All sockets in the room are 100% live.

JACK - Thank you.  I was careful and the difference is night and day as soon as the switch is flipped.  I considered a multi-meter to verify but I can't get to a neutral on the circuit without dismantling the box - unless you can tell me how to test without on the multi?